# What are engines available for Inventor Design Automation API? GET inventor.io/us-east/v2/Engines fails

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I'm trying to retrieve the available engines with the following request:

```
curl 
-H "Authorization: Bearer my_fresh_token"
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/inventor.io/us-east/v2/Engines
```

and I got: `{ "developerMessage":"The requested resource does not exist.","userMessage":"","errorCode":"ERR-002","more info":"`[`http://developer.api.autodesk.com/documentation/v1/errors/err-002`](http://developer.api.autodesk.com/documentation/v1/errors/err-002)`"}`

Requesting for Autocad engines everything goes well: `autocad.io/us-east/v2/Engines`

Am I using a wrong URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V2 is only for AutoCAD - nothing else is available publicly yet and I cannot provide the exact date when it will become available for Inventor.
Sorry for the bad news.
Hopefully we'll have more information to share at AU Germany and AU Las Vegas.

Edit:
Now we have a public beta for v3 of the API that supports Inventor and 3dsMax too. Soon it will support Revit as well. Have a look here https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview/